# Mongodb : find documents including references to sub-documents [node-mongodb-native]

Tags: mongodb, find

I have the following Mongodb Documents :

```
Users : {'_id' : '12345', 'fullname' : 'ABC'}
and 
Files : 
        {'_id' : 'File001', 'path' : 'pathA', 'Users_id' : '12345'}
        {'_id' : 'File002', 'path' : 'pathB', 'Users_id' : '12345'}
```

How do i query or find all 'Files' documents in a way that the 'Users_id' which is referencing to the 'Users' document has the full 'Users' Document?

Expected Output :

```
{'_id' : 'File001', 'path' : 'pathA', 'Users_id' : '12345', 'user' : {'_id' : '12345', 'fullname' : 'ABC'}}
{'_id' : 'File002', 'path' : 'pathB', 'Users_id' : '12345', 'user' : {'_id' : '12345', 'fullname' : 'ABC'}}
```

In this way, i could access the file owner's fullname  as such : file.user.fullname

I Appreciate any help from you guys.  Thank you.

**--- EDIT**

I am using node-mongodb-native to access the db.

Below is my code to retrieve it:

```
var files = db.collection ('Files');

files.find ({}, {}).toArray (function ( err, filesDoc){
    for ( var index in filesDoc) {
        var fileDoc = filesDoc [ index ];
        var users = db.collection ('Users');
        users.findOne ({'_id' : fileDoc.Users_id}, {}, function (errUser, userDoc){
            if ( ! errUser ) {
                fileDoc.user = userDoc;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

but this code is not assigning the user to all files doc and only assigns to the last element of the filesDoc array. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB doesn't support joins so you have to query for the User details separately.  If you're using node.js, [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) provides a [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) feature to help simplify this so you can do something like the following to pull in the user details:

```
Files.find().populate('Users_id')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was also thinking the same way of retrieving referenced documents, but I can't make it work with node-mongodb-native, please see Edit.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the cause of the issue.  The reason why my code returns a null user is because I saved File.Users_id as String and I am retrieving it using ObjectId.

I fixed my codes by converting Users_id String to ObjectId before saving the File.